# Why do i have to add a explicit casting when use a generics type with wildcard parameterized type?

Tags: java, types, casting

Here is the code:

```
public class Pair<X,Y> {
    private X first;
    private Y second;
    public Pair(X x, Y y) {
            first = x;
            second = y;
    }
    public X getFirst() { return first; }
    public Y getSecond() { return second; }
    public void setFirst(X x) { first = x; }
    public void setSecond(Y y) { second = y; }
}

final class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "a";
        Pair<?,?> pair = new Pair<String,Long>("limit", 10000L);
        String s = pair.getFirst();
}
```

this code doesn't work,because the object return by the method `getFirst()`cannot be converted to string：

```
Test.java:5: error: incompatible types: CAP#1 cannot be converted to String
                String s = pair.getFirst();
                                        ^
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
```

It seems that the compiler had added an implicit cast but failed.

But when i add a  explicit cast(`String s = (String)pair.getFirst()`),  it works.

Why does this happen ???

Comment: It happens because `Pair<?,?>` could be an Pair of anything - a `Pair<Long,String>` for example. You don't need to cast if you write `Pair<String, Long> pair = ...`

Comment: `pair` has a reference type of `Pair<?, ?>`. The only thing the compiler knows, is that the two generic arguments extend `Object`, so `pair.getFirst()` returns an `Object`. Of course, the *actual* type is indeed a `String`, and that's why the casting succeeds.
Of course, you should replace `Pair<?,?> pair = new Pair<String,Long>("limit", 10000L)` with `Pair<String, Long> pair = new Pair<>("limit", 10000L)` in order to ensure compile-time safety.

Comment: Casting is compiler-unsafety. Generics are a mechanism to provide compiler-safety.